# Discrete Math notation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Fill in with the correct notation.

(1) p denotes a person and A denotes the set of all people.

(a) p ∈ A

(b) A _ p

(2) B denotes the set of all mammals and A denotes the set of all animals.

(c) B ⊂ A

(d) A _ B

can someone help me with the blanks for (b) and (d)? thanks!

Comment: Without further context, it is almost impossible to say.  A good guess would be $\ni$ and $\supset$.

Comment: thanks that is right I think. I didn't know you could say A ∋ p but now I know. thank you.

Comment: P.S. I'm new to the forum. how do I mark that this question was answered? So no one else wastes their time looking at it? Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to mark it as answered unless someone actually posts and answer.  Comments don't count.

Comment: alright thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already seem to have known about the symbols $\in$ (is contained in), and $\subset$ (is a subset of).

The symbols you seems to be missing are $\ni$ (contains the element), and $\supset$ (is a superset of).

$a\in A$ is equivalent to saying $A\ni a$, similarly $A\subset B$ is equivalent to saying $B\supset A$.  This is analogous to saying that if $x<y$ (*meaning x is less than y*) that it follows that $y>x$ (*meaning y is greater than x*).